# Error when importing pandas to Jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, import, importerror

I am trying to import pandas to Jupyter notebook and get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'DtypeArg' from 'pandas._typing' (/Users/YA/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_typing.py)
```

My code is literally one line so far: `import pandas as pd`. Please, help me understand what is happening. Thank you!

Comment: try `conda update pandas` in your conda terminal

Comment: @Erfan, It returns "# All requested packages already installed".

Comment: What about doing it in the notebook, i.e., `!conda update pandas` or even `!pip install pandas ---upgrade`?

Comment: @MustafaAydın, I get "no such option: ---upgrade" when running the second line in the Jupyter notebook, and "All requested packages already installed" when running the first.

Comment: You put the exclamation marks in front, right? Interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following options in a regular terminal, (not in a Jupyter notebook or Jupyter terminal)

Option 1:

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas --upgrade
```

Option 2

```
pip install pandas==1.1.5
```

Source:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42506#issuecomment-878501500